# Google Analytics Big Query export

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

What is the time taken by google analytics to start exporting historical data into the google cloud after the linking is complete between Big Query and Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en):

> Once the linkage is complete, data should
>   start flowing to your BigQuery project **within 24 hours**. 1 file will be
>   exported each day that contains the previous day’s data, and 3 files
>   will be exported each day that contain the current day's data. We will
>   provide a historical export of the smaller of 10 billion hits or 13
>   months of data within 4 weeks after the integration is complete.

Comment: when is the integration said to be complete?

Comment: I'd say that once you see a lot of tables with data from previous days up to 13 months (called `ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD`) and **every day** you have a new table with data from the day before (also called `ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD`) and a table with data from the current day (`ga_sessions_intraday_YYYYMMDD`).